# Utilizing footnotes using the iopart document class

Tags: footnotes

I'm using a template from LaTeX that has this code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{iopart}
```

Every time I use the function `\footnote {text}`, even if I use `\footnote [1] {text}`, the footnote shows up as an `\fnysymbol` and not `\arabic` like I want it to. I tried adding this in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

But this doesn't seem to work whether I put it before or after the document start, or right before the line where I add the footnote. How can I make sure that the default for my document is to use arabic numbers for footnotes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem. Also, as you're using a non-standard class, please post it ass well or add a link so we can find it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much Phelype. I didn't know how to do this so I really appreciate it! https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~durduran/topost/iopart.cls this is a link to the details of the package. Is this adequate? OR would something else suffice?

Comment: Since it's a simple problem to reproduce, the class was enough. In case it was something more complicated we would need a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, `iopart` doesn't want footnotes.

In order to keep the symbols for the author part and make them become normal in the body of the document, you can define a `\mainmatter` command that does the necessary switches.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{iopart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\fnsymbol}{\arabic}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@thefnmark}{\fnsymbol}{\arabic}{}{}%
  \def\@makefnmark{\textsuperscript{\arabic{footnote}}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title[Author guidelines for IOPP journals]{Preparing an article for 
publication in an Institute of Physics Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}

\author{Neil Scriven\dag\ and Romneya Robertson\ddag  
\footnote[3]{To
whom correspondence should be addressed (romneya.robertson@iop.org)}
}

\address{\dag\ Production Editor, Institute of Physics 
Publishing, Dirac
House, Temple Back, Bristol BS1 6BE, UK}

\address{\ddag\ Electronic Services Specialist, Institute of Physics Publishing, 
Dirac House, Temple Back, Bristol BS1 6BE, UK}


\begin{abstract}
An abstract.
\end{abstract}

\mainmatter

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Fake}

Many authors use \LaTeX\ to produce their typescripts\footnote{abc}
and we can use the source code to produce the printed version;  this gives 
more rapid publication with a smaller chance of typographical
error.\footnote{def}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`iopart` redefines `\@makefntext`, `\@makefnmark`, and `\@thefnmark` to use `\fnsymbol` to number the footnotes. One alternative is to override these definitions to make them use `\arabic`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{iopart}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em\noindent 
 \makebox[1em][l]{\footnotesize\rm$\m@th{\arabic{footnote}}$}%
 \footnotesize\rm #1}
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{${\arabic{footnote}}\m@th$}}
\def\@thefnmark{\arabic{footnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text with\footnote{a footnote}.

\end{document}
```

another alternative is to make `\@fnsymbol` be `\@arabic`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{iopart}

\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text with\footnote{a footnote}.

\end{document}
```

What you use is up to you. The advantage of the first is that if you want to use `\fnsymbol` for something, it will work as expected. The second is less messy.

---

Also, I think you could put a `\setcounter{footnote}{0}` right after `\documentclass` because the footnote numbering appears to start at the second footnote... Class bug or feature?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is incredibly helpful. I am still hitting on glitch which is that next to my name I have a footnote and the number shows up as the same size as the letters in my name, but I want it to be a superscript like a normal footnote. How can I do this?

Comment: @JulietFlam-Ross Oh, I didn't notice this. As egreg said, apparently `iopart` isn't supposed to work with footnotes, but his answer fixed it to make it work. You should accept his answer :)